# How can I debug a program using scanf with ddd?

Tags: c++, c, gdb, scanf, ddd-debugger

When `ddd` encounters a `scanf` statement, it displays "Waiting until GDB gets ready" message. The debugging activity stops here. Please guide me of overcoming this bug.

I'm using an amd64 athlon processor.

Answer (score 6):

I am surprised that so much time has elapsed on this, so although I know little about ddd, it seems very likely that the problem is simply that gdb is waiting for the program which is blocked on a read waiting for input on stdin.  If you were running gdb directly, you could direct input to the program by using:

`run < input-file`

You need to give your program some input.

Comment: still the same problem persists dear friend. The debugger still displays "Waiting until GDB gets ready" message. this happens while using graphical ddd, not command line gdb.

Comment: I saw "Waiting until GDB gets ready" here a few days ago but the problem was that I had messed up the DDD config with bad font names.  I did an `rm -rf ~/.ddd` and the problem went away.  Apparently DDD can fail a number of different ways with nary any kind of a message. (font browsing btw requires the old xfontsel program to be installed)

Answer (score 2):

It's just like in gdb. You can input your values at the bottom pane of ddd. It's just that ddd is not very good at drawing the cursor to indicate that that's possible.